# A simple JS code and I am receiving the same result over and over again, I think, I may have done a logical error,

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS on my own and wanted to solve a challenge on my own but I think my logic in the code is wrong, since I am keep getting the same result/return over and over, which is 'There's a tie!'.

About the task:

The possible outcomes are:

bear mauls human.
human disarms gun.
gun shoots bear.
If there's a tie, then the game ends in a draw.

Challenge: Our code will break the game into four parts:

Get the user's choice.
Get the computer's choice.
Compare the two choices and determine a winner.
Start the program and display the results.

```
//Getting the user's choice.

let options = ['bear','human','gun'];

function getUsersChoice (){
    return usersChoice = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
getUsersChoice();

// Getting computer's choice.
function getComputersChoice (){
    return computersChoice = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
getComputersChoice();

//Compare the two choices and determine a winner.
function determineWinner (usersChoice , computersChoice){
        if(usersChoice ===  computersChoice){
        return 'There\'s a tie!';
        }
        if( usersChoice === 'bear'){
            if(computersChoice === human){
            return 'bear mauls human.';
            }else {
            return 'gun shoots bear.';
            }
        }
        if (usersChoice === 'human'){
            if(computersChoice === 'gun'){
            return 'human disarms gun.';
            }else {
            return ' bear mauls human.';
            }
        }
        if (usersChoice === 'gun'){
            if(computersChoice === 'bear'){
            return 'gun shoots bear.';
            }else {
            return 'human disarms gun.';
            }


        }




}
determineWinner();
```

Comment: The task is following: Bear human gun is just like Rock paper scissors. Each player chooses either bear, human, or gun. The items are compared, and whichever player chooses the more powerful item wins.

The possible outcomes are:

=> bear mauls human.
=> human disarms gun.
=> gun shoots bear.
=> If there's a tie, then the game ends in a draw.

Challenge: Our code will break the game into four parts:

=> Get the user's choice.
=> Get the computer's choice.
=> Compare the two choices and determine a winner.
=> Start the program and display the results.

Comment: You are calling `getUsersChoice()` and `getComputersChoice()` but you are not storing the results anywhere. Then when you call `determineWinner()`, you are not passing any values to it.

Comment: One thing that will really help you in the future is to use the chrome developer tools and the javascript debugger.  If you had debugged your code I think you would have seen the obvious problem your code has.  When things are not obvious, it's even more important.  You should also take advantage of `console.log()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hand over the choices.

```js
function getUsersChoice() {
    return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function getComputersChoice() {
    return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function determineWinner(usersChoice, computersChoice) {
    if (usersChoice === computersChoice) return 'There\'s a tie!';
    if (usersChoice === 'bear') {
        if (computersChoice === 'human') return 'bear mauls human.';
        return 'gun shoots bear.';
    }
    if (usersChoice === 'human') {
        if (computersChoice === 'gun') return 'human disarms gun.';
        return 'bear mauls human.';
    }
    if (usersChoice === 'gun') {
        if (computersChoice === 'bear') return 'gun shoots bear.';
        return 'human disarms gun.';
    }
}

let options = ['bear', 'human', 'gun'];
console.log(determineWinner(getUsersChoice(), getComputersChoice()));
```

Comment: I'm amused at the idea that getUsersChoice() is implemented as the computer randomly generating the choice for the "user"  :)

Comment: it can be changed to any other input of choice.

Comment: Sure, that was not a criticism, just an observation of the original code.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    let options = ['bear','human','gun'];

function getUsersChoice (){
    return options[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
var userChoice = getUsersChoice();

// Getting computer's choice.
function getComputersChoice (){
    return options[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
var computerChoice = getComputersChoice();

//Compare the two choices and determine a winner.
function determineWinner (usersChoice , computersChoice){
        if(usersChoice ===  computersChoice){
        return 'There\'s a tie!';
        }
        if( usersChoice === 'bear'){
            if(computersChoice === human){
            return 'bear mauls human.';
            }else {
            return 'gun shoots bear.';
            }
        }
        if (usersChoice === 'human'){
            if(computersChoice === 'gun'){
            return 'human disarms gun.';
            }else {
            return ' bear mauls human.';
            }
        }
        if (usersChoice === 'gun'){
            if(computersChoice === 'bear'){
            return 'gun shoots bear.';
            }else {
            return 'human disarms gun.';
            }


        }




}
determineWinner();
```

Comment: You really need to explain your answer.

Comment: actually you haven't declared the variables you used inside your determineWinner function